# Why are the results not automatically updated?

Tags: talend

I have create a simple soap service :

[image]

Between each request, the base is modified by other services. However, I still have the same result.

The lookup model is set to `Reload at each row`. What should normally refresh the data stream coming from the database.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is the request tDBInput :

```
SELECT 
   methodes.idMethode AS idDocument,
   methodes.nomMethode AS nomDocument,
   methodes.doc_docMaitre AS idDocMaitre,
   methodes.codeMethode AS codeDocument,
   typemethode.typeMethode AS typeDocument,
   donneshse.lienfichier AS nomFichier,
   donneshse.typeMIME AS typeMIME,
   LOWER(HEX(methodes.doc_token)) AS tokenDocument,
   '"+((String)globalMap.get("site"))+"' as test
FROM methodes

LEFT OUTER JOIN donneshse
 ON donneshse.idDonne=methodes.donHse

LEFT OUTER JOIN typemethode 
 ON typemethode.idTypeMethode=methodes.typeMethode

LEFT OUTER JOIN methodes_site 
 ON methode=idMethode

WHERE CONCAT(',', CONCAT('"+((String)globalMap.get("site"))+"', ',')) 
  LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%,', site), ',%')

GROUP BY idDocument
```

Where could I have made a mistake that makes the result always the same ?

Comment: Are you using "site" as a filter for your query in DBInput_1 ? could you share DBInput_1 query ?

Comment: Yes, I'am using it. I just add the Query of DBInput_1.

Comment: you are using "myKey" in the query posted, whether it is "site" on your first screenshot. perhaps not relevant but are you sure about naming of global variable ?

Comment: Sorry for this, between the first post and this last one I tried to redo the job to see what was wrong. I just edit with same value

Comment: The request  seem executed. At each call of the request row/s is changing. For example in the screen it's 44,78 row/s. Each time I call request in Soap Ui, this number is different

Comment: it seems that you have a component before tESBProviderRequest : which one is it ? Also something you could try is to divide your subjob into 2 : tESBProviderRequest->tSetGlobalVar (put the body of your request in a global Variable) then on component OK on tSetGlobalVar > tFixedFlow>tXMLMap. In tFixedFlow, get body from your globalVar. Perhaps having the whole flow in one subjob is inducing this bug.

Comment: The component before tESBProviderRequest is a connection at the data base. It's could be a good idea to test with out existing connection. Let me time to test this 2 options

Comment: @Corentin, I just test with out use `Existing Connection` in the  tDBInput_1, and now the row is update and change when data base change. I can't believe that the problem come from here. I will update the question to make appear all the job. Please can you make an answer to get the bounty. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248904/discussion-between-feulgen-and-corentin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In services, you'd best not declare the connection in a tDBConnection prior to the tESBProviderRequest component : either use a specific connection on tDBInput, open the tDBConnection after tESBProviderRequest, or declare tDBConnection in a prejob (in this case the connection is set up only when deploying the job).